# error while mapping : unknown setting [index.knn.algo_param.m]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to change mapping in elastic search and getting this error
https://ibb.co/q5LkfWz

"reason": "unknown setting [index.knn.algo_param.m] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings

and this is the PUT request i am trying to make

```
PUT posting 
{
   "settings":{
      "index":{
         "number_of_shards":1,
         "number_of_replicas":0,
         "knn":{
            "algo_param":{
               "ef_search":40,
               "ef_construction":40,
               "m":"4"
            }
         }
      },
      "knn":true
   },
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "vector":{
            "type":"knn_vector",
            "dimension":384
         },
         "title":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                   "index":false
               }
            }
         },
         "company":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "index":false
         },
         "location":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "index":false
         },
         "salary":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "index":false
         },
         "job_description":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "index":false
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this is an opensearch issue, not an Elasticsearch one

Answer (score 1):

The reason indicates that the [KNN plugin](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/knn/index/) is not installed on the OpenSearch cluster.